# Grammar Checker app in python using gingerit

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, spyder

I tried to create a grammar checking app in python using gingerit and flask. It shows some error the home page is displaying fine but after I enter the data and hit enter It shows:"Internal Error -500" And I think the error is in the index.html page.

Main.py:

```
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect
app= Flask (__name__) 
@app.route("/") 
def sent():
   if request.method == "GET": 
       return render_template("index.html")
   else:
       if not request.form["SENT"]: 
             return redirect("/")
@app.route('/sent correct', methods=["GET", "POST"]) 
def sent_correct():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    text = request.form["SENT"]
    parser = GingerIt() 
    print(parser.parse(text)['corrections'])
     result = parser.parse(text)['result'] 
    return render_template("index.html", output1=result)
app.run()
```

Index.html:
[Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbcmO.jpg)

[The app on the browser when executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9JaD.jpg)
[After hitting submit this is how it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QcAo.jpg)

Comment: The spacing of the `result = ...` line is wrong, and you have mixed single and double quotes in the last `return` line.  Is that literally how your code looks?

Comment: `app= Flask (_name_) ` ->  `_name_` is not defined (it should be `__name__`).  But we can't be sure of the exact cause unless you [edit] the question to include the complete error traceback.

Comment: Actually that is all an typo error the code itself doesnt have any sort of syntax errors